# GridView display partial imagebutton

Tags: gridview

in my app,scrollview working fine but all gridview display only partial imgebutons.
i have to display 6 imagebuttons and textview in each grid.3 grids wrking fine but below that it display only partial 3 buttons.. pls guide me what i m doing wrong.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/firstLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/latest_ringtone" >
            </ImageView>

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/grid1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/firstLabel"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
            </GridView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/scndLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/topofmonth" >
            </ImageView>

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/grid2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/scndLabel"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="3dp" >
            </GridView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thrdLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/alltime_hits" >
            </ImageView>

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/grid3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/thrdLabel"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="3dp" >
            </GridView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

works by extending Gridview &  override onMeasure().